# Measurable function by definition

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How to prove (by definition) that if $f:X\to R$ is measurable function, then [f] is also measurable? Here, I have to prove that for every $[c,\infty)$, $[f]^{-1}([c,\infty))$ is measurable.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $[x]$ the floor function of $x$?

Comment: @lxion Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c\in\mathbb{Z}$: $[f]^{-1}([c,\infty))=f^{-1}([c,\infty))$

Otherwise: $[f]^{-1}([c,\infty))=\\f^{-1}([c,\infty)) \cap (f^{-1}([c,[c]+1)))^c$

And these sets are measurable.